# Obter o número de ficheiros contidos em um diretório

Tags: python, linux

Estou utilizando o seguinte script:

```
import os
ler = os.system('ls livros | wc -l')
print(ler)
```

O objetivo era a variável `ler` receber o número de ficheiros existentes dentro de um diretório porém ela fica sempre com o valor `0` mesmo existindo ficheiros no diretório.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bibilioteca padrão [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) fornece uma interface bastante completa e portável de acesso ao sistema de arquivos do sistema operacional.

Ao invés de usar o método [`os.system()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=listdir#os.system) para executar comandos específicos, você pode fazer isso de maneira bem mais elegante combinando as funções [`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=listdir#os.listdir) e [`os.path.isfile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) para listar somente os arquivos de um determinado diretório:

```
import os, os.path

def listar_arquivos(diretorio):
    listagem = []
    for arquivo in os.listdir(diretorio):
        arquivo = os.path.join(diretorio,arquivo)
        if os.path.isfile(arquivo):
            listagem.append(arquivo)
    return listagem
```

Ou ainda:

```
import os, os.path

def listar_arquivos(diretorio):
    return [os.path.join(diretorio,arquivo)
        for arquivo in os.listdir(diretorio)
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(diretorio, arquivo))]
```

Testando:

```
import os, os.path

def listar_arquivos(diretorio):
    return [os.path.join(diretorio,arquivo)
        for arquivo in os.listdir(diretorio)
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(diretorio, arquivo))]

ls = listar_arquivos('/tmp')

# Exibe lista de arquivos
print(ls)

# Exibe a quantidade de arquivos
print(len(ls))
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/UntrueFrugalFilesize)

Comment: ele da um erro ele diz:
TypeError: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'list'
Sabe como resolver isso?

Comment: @HugoBarbosa Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/UntrueFrugalFilesize).

Comment: o meu nao retorna nada agora, consegui arranjar aquele problema porem nao retorna nada o objetivo era essa função estar dentro do metodo __init__ e quando arranca-se a GUI ele detetava quantos ficheiros estão disponiveis num determinado diretorio desta forma
import os, os.path
class teste:
 def listar_arquivos(diretorio='/livros'):
   listagem=[]
   for arquivo in os.listdir(diretorio):
   arquivo=os.path.join(diretorio,arquivo)
   if(os.path.isfile(arquivo)):
     listagem.append(arquivo)
  return listagem
  def __init__(self):
   a=self.listar_arquivos
   print(a)
teste

Comment: Que tal [isso](https://repl.it/repls/WarpedEqualMotion) ?!

Comment: funciona direitinho outra pergunta eu criei um diretorio chamado livro e para passar em parametro em tenho de meter /livro certo? e que quando tento passar ele devolve o erro No such file or directory: '/livro'

Comment: @HugoBarbosa Já tentou `./livro` ?

Answer (score 1):

Segundo a [documentação de `os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system), o retorno é o *exit status* do comando (e não a saída do comando em si), e zero geralmente [indica que o comando rodou normalmente, sem erros](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/The_exit_status_of_a_command#Exit_Status).

Já a saída do comando é enviada para a saída padrão (por exemplo, se rodar no terminal, aparecerá na própria tela).

Para obter a saída do comando da forma que você quer, use o [módulo `subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess):

```
import subprocess

cmd = "ls livros -1 | wc -l"    
out = subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
print(out.stdout)
```

Como a saída do comando é apenas um número, você pode convertê-lo para `int` se quiser:

```
quantidade = int(out.stdout.strip())
```

Usei [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) para remover a quebra de linha no final, que também é retornada em `out.stdout`.

---

Obs: `subprocess.run` foi adicionado no Python 3.5 - para versões anteriores, uma alternativa é usar [`Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen):

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(["ls", "/c/Users/hkotsubo/", "-1"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(["wc", "-l"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()
result = p2.communicate()

print(result[0].decode('ascii'))
# ou se quiser converter para int
quantidade = int(result[0])
print(quantidade)
```